# std::shared_ptr not updating its count

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to create a network of a custom `class Tile` inside another `class Board` which is storing a `std::array<std::shared_ptr<Tile>, 34>`. I am using `std::shared_ptr<Tile>` objects within `class Tile` to show which nodes are connected. However, when I initialise each of the 34 `Tile` objects, the not yet initialised objects included in the list do not get updated from `nullptr` to their own reference.

```
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

struct Tile;
template <const std::size_t N> using TileLink  = std::array<const std::shared_ptr<const Tile>, N>;
template <const std::size_t N> using TileArray = std::array<std::shared_ptr<const Tile>, N>;

struct Tile {
    /* surrounding tiles */
    const std::size_t ID;
    const std::size_t num_adj;
    const TileLink<6> adjacent;
    Tile (std::size_t id, std::size_t n, const TileLink<6> & arr) : ID (id), num_adj (n), adjacent (arr) { }
    ~Tile (void) = default;
};

class Board {
private:
    TileArray<34> tiles;
public:
    Board (void);
    ~Board (void) = default;
};

Board :: Board (void) {
    /* Column 1 */
    tiles[0]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 0, 3, TileLink<6>{ tiles[1],  tiles[4],  tiles[5],  nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr   });
    tiles[1]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 1, 4, TileLink<6>{ tiles[0],  tiles[2],  tiles[5],  tiles[6],  nullptr,   nullptr   });
    tiles[2]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 2, 3, TileLink<6>{ tiles[1],  tiles[6],  tiles[7],  nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr   });
    /* Column 2 */
    tiles[3]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 3, 2, TileLink<6>{ tiles[4],  tiles[9],  nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr   });
    tiles[4]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 4, 5, TileLink<6>{ tiles[0],  tiles[3],  tiles[5],  tiles[9],  tiles[10], nullptr   });
    tiles[5]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 5, 6, TileLink<6>{ tiles[0],  tiles[1],  tiles[4],  tiles[6],  tiles[10], tiles[11] });
    tiles[6]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 6, 6, TileLink<6>{ tiles[1],  tiles[2],  tiles[5],  tiles[7],  tiles[11], tiles[12] });
    tiles[7]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 7, 5, TileLink<6>{ tiles[2],  tiles[6],  tiles[8],  tiles[12], tiles[13], nullptr   });
    tiles[8]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 8, 2, TileLink<6>{ tiles[7],  tiles[13], nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr   });
    /* Columns 4 - 6 */
    ...
    ...
    ...
    /* Column 7 */
    tiles[31] = std::make_shared<Tile> (31, 3, TileLink<6>{ tiles[26], tiles[27], tiles[32], nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr   });
    tiles[32] = std::make_shared<Tile> (32, 4, TileLink<6>{ tiles[27], tiles[28], tiles[31], tiles[33], nullptr,   nullptr   });
    tiles[33] = std::make_shared<Tile> (33, 3, TileLink<6>{ tiles[28], tiles[29], tiles[32], nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr   });
}
```

The `std::array` I am passing to the `Tile` constructor does not change. How would I get it to change?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for making the question so long, I didn't really know how to make this a smaller example.

Comment: I doubt anybody will look into the code. Post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the problem with **as minimal as possible** code.

Comment: You can use a reference or pointer to it. Or a [referene wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) like `std::ref`.

Comment: why store the `TileLink` in a shared_ptr anyways? As long as the board exists, the tiles exist and the links should be valid. And if it is a 2D board and the tile links are just the neighbours, you could just store them in a 2D grid.

Comment: Specifying `void` as the parameter list `Board (void);` is a C-ism.  In C++, use `Board ();`, since in C++ land no parameters means "zero parameters", whereas in C land no parameters means "unknown number of parameters".

Comment: @Zaiborg thanks for the insight, the board is the grid I’m storing the tiles in - but the grid is not rectangular (it’s closer to hexagonal) and hence the weird connections.

Comment: @Eljay that’s not really relevant to the problem I’m demonstrating. If you have any thoughts on the question I’ve asked please leave a comment. But just so we are clear having `Board (void)` is perfectly valid C++ syntax for the example I have given, and just because something is C-syntax does not mean that it is wrong or inferior.

Comment: That's why I left it as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: with hex boards, there is a great site for it: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/ there is also explained how you can store your values in a 2d array as well as path finding and neighbours

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
tiles[0]  = std::make_shared<Tile> ( 0, 3, TileLink<6>{ tiles[1],  tiles[4],  tiles[5],  nullptr,   nullptr,   nullptr   });
```

`tiles[1]`, `tiles[4]`, and so on, are not yet initialized and are `shared_ptr` to nullptr. When you initialize `tiles[1]` later it doesn't change what is inside `tiles[0]`.

You are completely misusing `shared_ptr`. Since your tile array has a fixed size, just allocate once all the needed memory and then use non-owning pointers. Because *there is* a owner for the memory and it is `Board`.

Comment: I agree with the first part of the answer. But the second is not clearly written. I think you mean the following: `TileArray` should  be `std::array<const Tile, N>` and  `TileLink` should be `std::array<Tile const * const, N>`, right? That would actually not work due to the constness and the constructors of `Tile`. But I agree that `shared_ptr` is most ccertanly the wrong thing here. Maybe more  `TileArray` as  `std::array<std::unique_ptr<const Tile>, N>` and `TileLink` being `std::array<Tile const * , N>` but then there is still the problem that the pointers of `TileLink` are not const.

Comment: Ok, so `std::shared_ptr<>` is not correct in this scenario, and I should be using just `Tile` objects in the array in the `Board`, with unique references to the object in the adjacent list. But then how would I initialise the list in the array in the `Board` constructor?

Comment: Some constness has to go. Even the constructor cannot build the object correctly (this is indeed the problem of the OP). Remove the constness, use a single array to hold your Tiles, update all the links in the ctor body. Then declare you board as: `const Board theBoard;` and everything will be const from the clients perspective if that's really what you want... (but I doubt it)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem - thanks to @t.niese and @fjardon for your help.

I had to make `Tile` more complex to facilitate the real issue here: that I was unable to create a unique `Tile` object from std::array in the class. So I added a copy constructor and an assignment operator, removed the smart pointers and the `const`-ness and made the array of class type `Tile`.

```
class Tile;
template <const std::size_t N> using TileLink  = std::array<const Tile *, N>;
template <const std::size_t N> using TileArray = std::array<Tile, N>;

enum class OWNERSHIP { PLAYER_1, PLAYER_2, CONTESTED };

class Tile {
private:
    OWNERSHIP territory;
    /* surrounding tiles */
    std::size_t ID;
    std::size_t num_adj;
    TileLink<6> adjacent = { nullptr };
public:
    Tile (void) { }
    Tile (OWNERSHIP own, std::size_t id, std::size_t num, const TileLink<6> & arr);
    Tile (const Tile & rhs);
    Tile & operator = (Tile other);
    ~Tile (void) = default;
};

class Board {
private:
    TileArray<34> tiles;
    void create_col_1_and_7 (void);
    void create_col_2 (void);
    ...
    void create_col_6 (void);
public:
    Board (void);
    ~Board (void) = default;
};
```

Each of the initialisation now looks like:

```
tiles[0]  = Tile (OWNERSHIP::PLAYER_2,   0, 3, TileLink<6>{ &tiles[1],  &tiles[4],  &tiles[5],  nullptr,    nullptr,    nullptr    });
tiles[1]  = Tile (OWNERSHIP::CONTESTED,  1, 4, TileLink<6>{ &tiles[0],  &tiles[2],  &tiles[5],  &tiles[6],  nullptr,    nullptr    });
...
tiles[32] = Tile (OWNERSHIP::CONTESTED, 32, 4, TileLink<6>{ &tiles[27], &tiles[28], &tiles[31], &tiles[33], nullptr,    nullptr    });
tiles[33] = Tile (OWNERSHIP::PLAYER_1,  33, 3, TileLink<6>{ &tiles[28], &tiles[29], &tiles[32], nullptr,    nullptr,    nullptr    });
```